# Using property in Django

Tags: django, properties, django-views

I need help with the following situation.

My app has the following models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_sequential_nr = models.IntegerField(primary_key=true)
    person_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    person_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)

    @property
    def _summarize_goods(self):
        return self.goods_set.all().aggregate(Sum('good_value')).values()
    patrimony = property(_summarize_goods)

class Goods:
    person_sequential_nr = models.Foreignkey()
    good_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    good_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
```

Year is a string like 2012, 2010, 2008, etc
person_sequential_nr is specific (different) for each year.
person_id is the same for all years.

The intention of _summarize_goods is to totalize all goods of a person in a specific year.

***1) How can I get the top ten people with the highest patrimonies?***

When I call **Person.patrimony** it says *"TypeError: 'property' object is not callable"*
    **Person._summarize_goods** works, but I have no idea how to order it.

***2) How can I calculate the patrimony variation from of a person from one year to another (in the past)?***

I would like to have something like: **variation = (patrimony(year='2012')/patrimony(year='2010') - 1) * 100**
    I suppose that variation should be also a property, because I would like to use it to order some records.
    An additional problem is the the person data may exist in 2012, but may not exist in a year in the past (e.g. 2010). So I need to handle this situation.

***3) How can I create a view to show the patrimony of a person?***

**self.goods_set.all().aggregate(Sum('good_value'))** was returning a dictionary, so I added .values() to extract only the values of it, then I got a list.
    But wen I use **str(Person._summarize_goods)** it seemns that I still have a list. 
    Because when I call:

```
all_people = Person.objects.all()
people_list = [[p.person_name, str(p._summarize_goods)] for p in all_people]
output = ','.join(people_list)
return HttpResponse(output)
```

It shows an error referring the line output =

*TypeError at /
sequence item 0: expected string, list found*

### **EDITING...**

Find some answers:
After removing the decoration (thanks Daniel) Person.patrimony is working so:

***1) How can I get the top ten people with the highest patrimonies?***
This was solved with the code below:

```
def ten_highest_pat():
    people_2012 = Person.objects.all().filter(year=2012)
    return sorted(people_2012, key=lambda person: person.patrimony, reverse=True)[:10]
```

***2) How can I calculate the patrimony variation from of a person from one year to another (in the past)?***

I tried the code below, which works, but is too slow. So I would thank you if someone has a sugestion how can I improve it.

```
def _calc_pat_variation(self):
        c = Person.objects.all().filter(person_id = self.person_id, year__lt=self.year).order_by('-year')
        if c.count() >= 1 and c[0].patrimony != 0:
            return ((self.patrimony / c[0].patrimony) - 1) * 100
        else:
            return 'Not available'
    pat_variation = property(_calc_pat_variation)
```

Comment: Not sure why you're using both the property decorator and the old function wrapper

Comment: What Daniel said. Also, at first sight, why not make it a class method?

Comment: Daniel,
Thank you. I shouldb´t have use the decorator. I cut it off and now the property works as I expected. Person.patrimony gives no error.
But the question remains. 
Do you know how can I order the person patrimony?

Comment: LaundroMat,
I would like to order the people by the patrimony, this is why I am using property. Could I do this with a class method?